# Math question regarding complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

So.I have to describe the set of points which satisfies $Re(z)*[Im(z)-x^3] >0$
so as you may know,$Re(z)=x$ and $Im(z)=y$.

We have $x*(y-x^3)>0$
What does this describe on the plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it is $xy - x^4 > 0$, it looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+xy+-+x%5E4+%3E+0+). You can also plot a [surface](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+xy+-+x%5E4) obtained by setting $w = s t - t^4$, and looking at where it's positive.

To expand, if $x > 0$, then it's the region $y > x^3$ lying above the curve $y = x^3$. For $x < 0$, the inequality is reversed.

Comment: No,I mean thank you,I know this,but my teacher wants me to describe this to him with words...

Comment: @nothere I expanded my comment to include a non-graphical description.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the 2 cases where a product ab is positive:  i)$a>0$, and $b>0$, then you have the region $x>0$ and $y>x^3$ (where and, actually means intersection) , and then consider the other case $a<0, b<0$ similarly.